# Action to directly export selected features as GPX

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, ogr2ogr, gpx, actions

I would like to **directly** export selected tracks of a line layer as gpx. The common way is:

1. Select the line-layer
2. select the tracks for export
3. right-click on the layer -> save selected features as...
4. choose gpx-format, a filename and EPSG:4326 as CRS
5. hit OK-Button

But this takes too much time. So I'm looking for a fast solution. I know, the Layer-Actions could be perfect for this task!

How do I export selected features as gpx to a fixed file path with QGIS actions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it were a single feature to export you could use an action with canvas scope (i.e., interacting with the canvas), but since you may export several features, an **action with layer scope** fits better.

[image]

Action's code:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

path = "/tmp/gpx/sample.gpx"
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer("[% @layer_id %]")

if layer.selectedFeatureCount():
    result, error_string = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(
                layer,
                path,
                "utf-8",
                QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326),
                "GPX", 
                onlySelected=True,
                datasourceOptions=["GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=ON"],
                layerOptions=["FORCE_GPX_ROUTE=YES"])

    if result == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
        iface.messageBar().pushSuccess(
            "Export2GPX", 
            "Exported {count} lines to <a href='file://{path}'>{path}</a>".format(
                count=layer.selectedFeatureCount(), 
                path=path))
    else: 
        iface.messageBar().pushWarning("Export2GPX", "Ouch! Errors exporting: {}".format(error_string))
else:
    iface.messageBar().pushInfo("Export2GPX", "First select some features...")
```

---

Note 1: *There is a new method (`writeAsVectorFormatV2`) for exporting vector layers in the API. You can find the same action's code using such method [in this link](https://gist.github.com/gacarrillor/9ffdb819f937d7a0fab4c492ac38908b).*

Note 2: *Of course you should tweak the code snippet so that it reflects you intention. For instance, I'm forcing the output to be Routes with parameter `FORCE_GPX_ROUTE`. You could also use random file names so that you don't overwrite previous exports.*

Comment: you were some minutes faster than me :-) what do you think about adding some error handling and show messages if the export fails? https://gist.github.com/thbaumann/2ee1657d913e6706dd41d2e16a189c6e#file-export_as_gpx-py-L22

Comment: I had just added error handling, but showing error message would be handy, right! I'll borrow that from your link, thanks.

Comment: What I have to do, if I want a single gpx-file for each selected feature named by the filed "name"?

Comment: I see 2 options: 1) You could use the "Convert Format" algorithm for vectors, where you can iterate selected  features to get independent outputs. I don't know if you can name output laters according to an attribute, for that you should read the OGR docs; and 2) Add more Python logic to the action, first saving selected feature ids, and then iterating through those ids and saving with its proper name. Let me know if you need more help.